# Does Application.cfc take more execution time than Application.cfm?

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

We are moving from Adobe ColdFusion 8 to 10.
We have applications using Application.cfm. We decided to start using Application.cfc as it offers more customized approach. 
I was checking on how to convert Application.cfm to Application.cfc and noticed that Application.cfc with same amount of code as in Application.cfm takes more execution time than when using Application.cfm. 
For example if Application.cfm takes 150ms, Application.cfc takes 630ms.
Is that how it is?

I did not go into any other detail. Please let me know  if you need more details.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be how it is, might be your code. Just deal with it and use `Application.cfc`. The benefits outweigh any minor performance issues like that.

Comment: Did you .cfm file have associated files for onSessionStart, etc?   If so, did you put all the code into the appropriate functions in .cfc?

Comment: Thank you @AdrianJ.Moreno for your reply. We are going to use Application.cfc, no two thoughts about it. Just wanted to know.

Comment: Thank you @DanBracuk for your reply. We have couple of files for sessions. Application.cfm has certain request scope variables assignment and some code to authorize/unauthorise usage of certain pages to certain users. It also has some code on Error handling.

Answer (score 1):

I have found `application.cfc` to run faster than `application.cfm`, but it's been years since I've used `application.cfm`. I would tend to agree with Adrian that it might be your code.

You can use `getTickCount()` to track how long sections of your code are taking to run.

The example below would track the runtime of the entire request. You would need to log or output the final value of `local.loadTime`. You can calculate the difference between a tickCount before and after *any* block of code to see how long it took to execute.

```
boolean function onRequestStart() {
    request.startTime = getTickCount();
    return true;
}

void function onRequestEnd() {
    if (structKeyExists(request, "startTime") && request.startTime > 0) {
        local.loadTime = getTickCount() - request.startTime;
    }
}
```